# IIS not UTF-8 encoding logs correctly. Bug?

Tags: iis-8, logstash

My server's log file is set to encode in UTF-8, it does not seem to be encoding the text correctly.

For example the cookie section sometimes has a £ sign in. But in the log it is written as 0xA3 not 0xC2 0xA3.

Is this a bug?

I'm trying to pass the files through logstash and get 1000's of encoding warnings...

Comment: "Is this a bug?"  Maybe.  Or a misconfiguration.  We can't tell from here, based on what you've told us.